# Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric- How to find

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I am selecting and inserting data in another table in SQL Server and getting the following error as:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric.

How can I identify which data causing this issue?

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
      myNum DECIMAL(10, 4)
);

INSERT INTO foo 
    SELECT 1234.567;
```

Comment: The only way to get the help is to show your code

Comment: please add specific columns DataTypes and size

Comment: The best Pseudo-SQL I can offer in the absence of any sample code: `SELECT YourMoneyColumn, [Other Relevant Columns] FROM YourTAble WHERE TRY_CONVERT(numeric(YourScale, YourPrecision),YourMoneyColumn) IS NULL;`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b51cd

Comment: The code you have supplied doesn't generate an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try_convert()`:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where try_convert(decimal(10, 4), col) is null;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_1(col1 DECIMAL(2,0))
CREATE TABLE #tmp_2(col2 DECIMAL(12,0))
CREATE TABLE #errors (error_value VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #tmp_2 VALUES (1222.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp_2 VALUES (122222.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp_2 VALUES (1.00)

DECLARE @rec DECIMAL(12,0)

DECLARE get_errors CURSOR FOR SELECT col2 FROM #tmp_2 
OPEN get_errors
FETCH NEXT FROM get_errors INTO @rec
WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
INSERT #tmp_1 VALUES (@rec)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO #errors VALUES (@rec)
END CATCH
        FETCH NEXT FROM get_errors INTO @rec
END
CLOSE get_errors
DEALLOCATE get_errors

GO 
SELECT * FROM #tmp_1
SELECT * FROM #errors
DROP TABLE #tmp_1
DROP TABLE #tmp_2
DROP TABLE #errors
```

Comment: is any other solution other than cursor..i have 11 lakh records

Comment: Save your records to the file, then `bulk insert` into the table with the `ERRORFILE` option, this option will allow you to write the wrong records to the file, you can also specify `MAXERRORS`, in which you indicate how many found incorrect inserts the bulk insert is to break @vmb

Comment: @vmb yes, a `CURSOR` will be an awfully slow way to find the problem. You haven't, however, yet posted your code, so how can the volunteers here hope to post one? :)